Were my comments overly provocative?
This Stack Overflow answer seemed to come off immediately with a very harsh stance against a JavaScript feature. In fact calling it "trash". Okay, I'm cool with that, but I'm therefore going to assume you know all the ins and outs of said feature. That you would know enough to earn the right to then label the feature as such.
But as I read on in his answer, I got the feeling that he might not have as good a grasp on the feature as would warrant that kind of vitriol towards it, so I felt some pushback was necessary. So I gave my perspective in the comments in a way to try and challenge their views with what I believe to be some basic misunderstandings of the subject matter (JavaScript Symbols).
Then out of the blue he posted a comment which I believe to be uncalled for, calling me an idiot. Do my comments on his answer come out so provocative as to warrant that type of response?
I didn't even downvote his answer either, so I am really struggling to see where this kind of hate would have arisen from. I am posting a picture to preserve the comment since comments can be deleted:


No, your comments were perfectly civil.  Some people react badly to even the implication that they're wrong about something.  Within the past day, someone described edits fixing grammar and generally improving a question's organization, or for anything that is not an "absolutely compelling reason, (possibly objectionable language or whatever)", as "rude and unacceptable and potentially violates the TOS".  Sigh, flag it (as several users did, resulting in its deletion), and move on.  For something that offensive, you might also consider (in the future) flagging the post to ensure mods see it.

User in question was suspended for a year, so their reaction to your comment was obviously uncalled for, and also apparently not out of the norm since being suspended for a year is a pretty significant punishment. Yes, I know suspension are not punishments, but they actually are in cases of rude behavior (IMO)

Ugh. Answers are supposed to be factual, not riddled with personal opinions and recommendations. Someone was treating Stack Overflow like Reddit.

@Gimby Eh, plenty of good answers go well beyond just stating objective facts and assert a best way to do something, or recommend for or against some practice, based upon some weighing of factors and arguments that isn't totally objective. There's nothing wrong with that in the abstract. The answer being discussed here just happens to be poorly argued and not really understand the typical use case of symbols in the first place. It's bad because the particular subjective argument it makes is bad, not because subjective arguments per se are bad or inappropriate for SO.

Funny how the people who are rude and insulting (on this site or anywhere else in life) never seem to ask themselves whether their behavior was appropriate.

No behaviour warrants bad behaviour.

@MarkAmery within limits and with the appropriate timing, starting off an answer with a "this is useless trash"... that's a Reddit post. The only thing a reader can do moving forward from that point, is not take anything seriously.

@Gimby: I disagree. Symbol is easily abused and it sounds like OP got the fallout from somebody else abusing it.

His answer would've better been kept, with his comments removed.

It all boils down to the old axiom "There is an asshole in every crowd, and the bigger the crowd the more assholes there are in it.". There is no telling why he came back the way he did. In my experience a responsive comment like that is generally grounded in insecurity (which it looks like you astutely picked up on), and because he lacked the background to discuss the pros and cons of the code-issue, he chose to sling an ad hominem hoping to bully his way out of the situation. Sad that is the way a growing minority seem to approach technical discourse.

There's no reason to bother to post something to meta every time someone violates the TOS. Are such violations warranted? Of course not, and it's problematic that you think they could be. And struggling to understand where the behavior comes from? It comes from molecular interactions inside the fellow ... perhaps his gut biome is out of whack, or his gf left him. You're assuming a tight causal coupling between what you wrote and his behavior but there isn't one and you lack the knowledge of causal factors  needed to answer your sort of question.

No, your comments were not overly provocative. Their response was not acceptable. Disagreeing with someone does not make it acceptable to call them an idiot or tell them to stop coding. The Code of Conduct states:

… we expect all users to treat one another with kindness and respect …

While that comment is gone now, you can (and should) flag comments like that as It contains harassment, bigotry, or abuse. (You can also flag comments as It's unfriendly or unkind for less offensive comments)
As Ryan M (mod) said, you can consider flagging the post. This way, even if the comment gets auto removed, a mod can take a look and consider further action (mod message, suspension, etc.)

This answer is based off an MSE comment I wrote regarding this situation.

I regret that post was deleted. (Offensive comment gone is good ...) ; I am reasonably certain that the poster ran across a case where a predecessor misused symbols and had to write some horrible code to fix it.

@Joshua hmmm... reads more to me like they wanted enums in JS, JS added a feature that maybe kinda sorta looks like enums if you squint, but wasn't enums, and the OP is all butthurt that they got a poor substitute for enums. I have no idea how that person reached the conclusion that Symbols were in any way  related to enums (maybe your hypothetical crimes against decency code the OP had to fix/workaround?) but that's still no excuse for sounding off about something they clearly don't understand.
